# Cannot bind data with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to build a geojson map representing every county in the U.S. using d3, and then dynamically change the colors of the shapes after fetching a csv file from the server.

Each county shape has a unique identifier assigned as an attribute within the svg path and is nested within the following style of div: `<div id="map"><svg ...><path ...></path></svg></div>`):

```
<path class="county" cid="49003" d="M268.97942180906057,
180.25136249051877L267.99968608232916,179.94417907047466L266.73835706796865,
181.58920557665408L263.8700579925135,181.0924673795946L259.5224347320402,
185.30429000298852L255.0646299840323,185.9781064759694L237.98063840912738,
182.81739842586433L241.51437533212444,164.45244088140475L255.62126287079593,
166.99664084530673L266.95905635804127,169.0065343660998L268.07266792127234,
171.7741286687334L267.5663893622565,174.8022351145563L267.9956982687371,
178.0311646832157L268.89925024903414,178.0929836991428Z"></path>
```

I'm able to select the elements with d3 and print attribute values to the console, but I cannot seem to add or change any of the attributes.

Here is a sample of the code that I'm trying to use:

```
bar.forEach(function(d, i){
    d3.select('#map').select('.county[cid="' + d[1] + ']"').attr('foo', 'bar')
});
```

The bar variable is csv data loaded earlier in the script:

```
bar = data.map(function(d) { return [d["n"], d["i"], +d["t"]]; });
```

This seems like such an easy and obvious solution, but cannot figure out why this won't work. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The critical part was the placement of the quotation marks within the selector:

The original:

```
d3.select('#map').select('.county[cid="' + d[1] + ']"').attr('foo', 'bar')
```

... becomes (notice the double quotation mark by the closing bracket near .attr):

```
d3.select('#map').select('.county[cid="' + d[1] + '"]').attr('foo', 'bar')
```

I've no idea how I was able to return the selected object array when I printed it to the console.log.